# How to use = render @users, when _user.html partial is in different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have following code in AdminUsers controller

```
class AdminUsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.where(role: 'admin')
  end
end
```

And my index.html.haml looks like this

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Name
      %th Age
      %th role
  %tbody
    = render @users
```

Now Rails is trying to find `_user.html.haml` partial inside `UsersController`, but my partial is inside `AdminUsersController`. Is there any way I can tell Rails to looks for partial inside `AdminUsersController` ?

I can solve the error by moving my partial under UsersController or by writing loop like this:

```
 - @users.each do |user|
    %tr
      // code
```

But it will be nice if I can use rails shorthand `= render @users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the custom partial path and pass the `@users` collection to it. Your code should look like:

```
= render partial: "admin_users/user", collection: @users
```

Read details on [Rendering Collections](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)